# How to hedge a long stock with the corresponding volatility ETF

Tags: volatility, vix, etf, delta-hedging, spx

Let us say I want to establish a market neutral position. So if I buy 50 shares of stock (SPY) and I want to delta hedge, I sell an ATM covered call. So that brings the position delta to 0.

Now, I could have also hedged by buying the corresponding volatility ETF VIXY. Since when SPY goes up, VIXY goes down. And vice versa.

So how can I figure out how many shares of VIXY to buy to hedge approximately 50 shares of SPY.

Comment: Could you specify what you like to hedge? Do you want to remove volatility risk, beta, both, minimize variance or something else? Also note that _"when SPY goes up, VIXY goes down"_ is only partially correct since, according to my data, annual correlation is currently at about -0.81. So maybe you can generalize your question?

Comment: I would like to remove directional bias buy purchasing SPY and VIXY. Now what should be the ratio of SPY:VIXY...how to calculate that?

Comment: I think I still don't understand your question because to me SPY looks like buying pure market direction. Can you elaborate why building an equal amount in a short position to your long position or weighting your short by the correlation coefficient between long and short asset is not applicable?

Comment: Got it thanks.. I need to hedge by the correlation coefficient between vixy and spy. It is there hidden in your comment. thank you